# Is it halal to eat meat of dead human being if there is nothing to eat in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, meat, people, disasters

> No, it is not halal to eat the meat of a dead human being in Islam. The consumption of human flesh is strictly prohibited in Islam, regardless of the circumstances. In the Quran, God states that he has created all of the inhabitants of the earth for the purpose of living in peace and harmony, and that no one has the right to take the life of another person or to consume their flesh. The Prophet Muhammad also taught that the taking of a single human life is equivalent to the destruction of all of humanity, and that the punishment for such a grave sin is severe. As such, it is never acceptable to eat the meat of a dead human being, regardless of the circumstances.

I have been answered by [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/chat) to the question *"Is it halal to eat meat of dead human being if there is nothing to eat in Islam?"*

Do you agree? Why?

Comment: Protip: retry the same prompt multiple times to get different responses every time, even slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual ruling on consumption of Human flesh is as follows:

- Human flesh is haram in normal circumstances.
- In-case of necessity (no other food available and you are about to starve to death):

  - it is still not permitted to kill a living human to eat their flesh. This applies to one whose life is protected (an innocent Muslim or Dhimmi). However the Hanbalis and Shaf'is have specified that it is permissible to kill a person whose blood is lawful (such as a kafir harbi, an apostate, a highway robber, or a muhsan adulterer) and to eat their flesh in this case.
  - there is difference of opinion among the jurists on whether an already dead person's flesh can be consumed:

    - The Hanafis and Shafi'is consider it permissible because they claim that the life of the living has more sanctity. And protecting it has greater priority.
    - The Malikis, Hanbalis and one saying of the Shafi'is is that it is still forbidden based on the hadith demanding respect for the body of the dead:

      > كسر عظم الميت ككسره حيا
      >
      > Breaking a dead man's bone is like breaking it when he is alive
      >
      > <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3207)</sup>

**Ref:** The Encyclopedia of Islamic jurisprudence [28/199](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk28/page/n198/mode/2up?view=theater) and [42/202](https://archive.org/details/FPmfkmfk/mfk42/page/n202/mode/2up?view=theater)

As for ChatGPT's response: The overall verdict is correct from the pov of at least some madhabs. But it makes a false claim about the content of the Quran, as there is no verse which explicitly says what it claims.